# Power BI Visual Running Total adds up

Tags: powerbi, dax

My Sales per Month visual looks like the first part of the picture.

To show the running total of transactions I use this Measure:

```
Sum Sales Running Total = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(SalesTable),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(SalesTable),
        SalesTable[CreatedOn] <= MAX(SalesTable[CreatedOn])
    )
)
```

If I choose only one year by slicer I get a correct visual for the running total. As you can see on the picture.

But if I choose multiple years by slicer for the running total visual, the visual adds all the data up instead of overlapping the graphs. See the lower part of the picture.

[image]

The correct sum of transactions is marced green and the wrong sum is marced red.

How can i prevent the visual form summing up the running totals in the visual?

Comment: You have to use SalesTable year = MAX SalesTable year also in the filter. use && operator to add this logic to the filter method. It will work fine

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand how to implement this in my existing DAX formula.
Could you give additional help or correct my Measure?

Comment: Able to come for a chat?

Comment: sure, where to go?

Comment: Please come to this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244281/power-bi-visual-running-total-adds-up

Comment: Sum Sales Running Total = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(SalesTable),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(SalesTable),
        SalesTable[CreatedOn] <= MAX(SalesTable[CreatedOn]) && YEAR(SalesTable[CreatedOn]) = MAX(YEAR(SalesTable[CreatedOn]))
    )
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi This behavior is happening because of the group by. modify the measures are below.

```
Count of Booths Running Total = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(dlg_V_Booth_per_Event),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(dlg_V_Booth_per_Event),
        dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[CreatedOn] <= MAX(dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[CreatedOn]) 
        && dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[RunningMonth] <= MAX(dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[RunningMonth]) 
        && dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[EventName] = max(dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[EventName])
    )
)

Sum of Booth Space Running Total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[BoothSpace]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(dlg_V_Booth_per_Event),
        dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[CreatedOn] <= MAX(dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[CreatedOn])
        && dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[RunningMonth] <= MAX(dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[RunningMonth]) 
        && dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[EventName] = max(dlg_V_Booth_per_Event[EventName])
    )
)
```